# Painful slow docker PHP setup on Windows

Tags: php, apache, docker

I run Docker for Windows with Hyper-V, 4 cores and 8GB RAM but page loads of my PHP project are in the order of 40 seconds per page.

My setup uses self signed certificates, but I think the problem is related to something else.

During my docker build I get the following warning:

> ---> Running in 46329f96a79f
>   Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2[Mon Jun 11 09:17:26.151516 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 23] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
>   [Mon Jun 11 09:17:26.151605 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 23] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Since non-https pages load also very slow, I think it is something else.

My Docker file is as follows

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY server.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
COPY server.key /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN apt-get update &&\
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes --quiet ca-certificates 
curl git &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl -Lsf 'https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux- 
amd64.tar.gz' | tar -C '/usr/local' -xvzf -
ENV PATH /usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
RUN go get github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail
RUN cp /root/go/bin/mhsendmail /usr/bin/mhsendmail
RUN echo 'sendmail_path = /usr/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr mailhog:1025' > 
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./ /var/www/html/
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
COPY dev.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.conf
RUN service apache2 restart
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

When I click a link, it shows Waiting... in de browser bar for ~40sec, but showing the page content itself is pretty fast

Could it be a DNS issue?

Comment: Are you using volume share to put the code inside? If so try putting the whole code also inside the docker image and see if that speeds up stuff for you

Comment: No I don't think I'm sharing a volume. I use COPY ./ /var/www/html/ to copy all my code over to the docker container.

Comment: dont copy your source or you'll need to restart every time you edit something. try using a docker compose like the one i made https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: @delboy1978uk The entire docker build does *not* restart if you edit something that isn't on the first line of the dockerfile. Docker is friendly and will use cache by default when rebuilding images. Everything up to a changed or edited dockerfile instruction will attempt to use cache. However its for situations the where rapid configuration and testing would be satisfied by attaching to a container in question (if possible for the imaged container), and making the changes inside the container and save the configurations with a `docker commit`

Comment: the update on edit feature is a different challenge to tackle. It is not related to the speed problem I face right now I guess

Comment: Are you using Firefox browser? If true, have you tried to use a "network" tab in developer tools to see which part of your page is slow? It looks like that your page contains resources which can not be loaded for some reason and this can be a cause.

Comment: @user3411864 I've had same issue, my pc is i 5 with 8 gb ram. it took me long time to load an ajax request, and my live server was faster than my local server. so it wasn't case of the docker, it was windows. I have install ubuntu in my pc and it's unbelievable fast. i was so surprised, i thought it was my code that slow.

Comment: @IvanVartanyan I used the network tab in Chrome. It doesn't show any request until the 40 seconds are over and the page is start loading

Comment: Are request slow with or without https? And What is the uri you use to access the application?

Comment: What is your code doing? Does it connect to a database?

Comment: It is a webshop with a mysql databse behind it. I noticed all my $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] are blank. After 2 months debugging I'm still not found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I will share with you my docker settings using PHP + Redis + MySQL + Nginx, see if it will be useful for you!

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev

# Add Microsoft repo for Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for Linux
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update

# Install Dependencies
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libgss3 \
    odbcinst \
    msodbcsql \
    locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-4.1.8preview sqlsrv-4.1.8preview \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsybdb.a /usr/lib/

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN mkdir -p /code
ENV HOME=/code
WORKDIR $HOME

USER root
COPY ./ $HOME
```

In this docker file has an SQLServer connection plugin too (I have many projects that I have integrated with it).

Now my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
    container_name: your_web_container_name
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./:/code
        - ./host.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
        - php:php
redis:
    container_name: your_redis_container_name
    image: redis
php:
    container_name: your_php_container_name
    build: ./
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./:/code
    links:
        - db
        - redis
db:
    container_name: your_database_container_name
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=docker
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
```

The default.conf of the nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I hope it could be helpful to you.